C# Dotnet 6: Application Insights with custom TelemetryInitializer, can't use TelemetryConfiguration.Active anymore
I'm trying to refactor a project that's a windows service/jobs project, from .net framework 4.7.2 to dotnet 6.
Here's the code how it is now:
public static void InitializeUsingOldMethod(TelemetryOptions options)
{
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists("ApplicationInsights.config"))
    {
        return;
    }

    var xml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("ApplicationInsights.config");
    var fromFile = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateFromConfiguration(xml);

    var configuration = TelemetryConfiguration.Active;
    configuration.DefaultTelemetrySink.Initialize(fromFile);
    configuration.InstrumentationKey = fromFile.InstrumentationKey;
    configuration.TelemetryChannel = fromFile.TelemetryChannel;
    configuration.TelemetryInitializers.AddRange(fromFile.TelemetryInitializers);
    configuration.TelemetryChannel = fromFile.TelemetryChannel;
    configuration.TelemetrySinks.AddRange(fromFile.TelemetrySinks);
    configuration.ApplicationIdProvider = fromFile.ApplicationIdProvider;

    string parameter = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationInsightsParameter"];

    configuration.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new JobsTelemetryInitializer(parameter));
}

public class JobsTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public string Parameter { get; private set; }

    public JobsTelemetryInitializer(string parameter)
    {
        Parameter = parameter;
    }

    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        var context = telemetry.Context;

        context.Cloud.RoleName = "Jobs";
        context.Component.Version = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();

        if (telemetry is ISupportProperties supported)
        {
            supported.Properties["Parameter"] = parameter;
            supported.Properties["Product"] = "Blabla";
        }
    }
}

But this no longer works because of "TelemetryConfiguration.Active" being obsolete in dotnet 6. Now when I install this Windows service locally, nothing logs to ApplicationInsights anymore. However locally, when debugging in Visual Studio, it still works!
How can I change this code so I can log to ApplicationInsights again once the service is installed as a Windows Service?

If the application doesn't naturally fit into a dependency injection (DI) scenario, you can explicitly create and manage the TelemetryConfiguration instance yourself. Please refer this doc.


Instead of relying on TelemetryConfiguration.Active, you'll create a TelemetryConfiguration instance manually and pass it around as needed.

Create a workerservice application in visual studio code.
Here we are manually managing the TelemetryConfiguration instance, avoiding issues with static singletons like TelemetryConfiguration.Active.

Configure Application Insights and inject it into the Worker class.

Program.cs:
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace WorkerService1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    // Add Application Insights telemetry
                    services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, JobsTelemetryInitializer>();
                    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();

                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                })
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
}


Update the constructor to accept TelemetryClient, and log telemetry events alongside the logger.

Worker.cs:
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WorkerService1
{
    public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
        private readonly TelemetryClient _telemetryClient;

        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, TelemetryClient telemetryClient)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _telemetryClient = telemetryClient;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var timeNow = DateTimeOffset.Now;
                
                _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", timeNow);
                
                // Track custom event in Application Insights
                _telemetryClient.TrackEvent("WorkerExecutionEvent", new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "ExecutionTime", timeNow.ToString() }
                });

                await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
    }
}


Created JobsTelemetryInitializer to initialize custom telemetry properties.

JobsTelemetryInitializer.cs:
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;

namespace WorkerService1
{
    public class JobsTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
    {
        public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {
            telemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleName = "WorkerService1";
            telemetry.Context.Component.Version = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
        }
    }
}

appsettings.json:
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "Your_Connection_String_Here"
  }
}

Application running successfully:

Traces:

